# Flask App results in Application Error when deployed through Heroku due to Error=H10

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am attempting to deploy a simple Flask app through Heroku, yet I am receiving an H10 Error. I am manually deploying with Github on the Heroku website.

I have tried using to commands 'heroku restart', heroku ps:scale web=1, pip freeze > requirements.txt, and dynos and changing my Procfile to include -b :$PORT, changing the PORT in my flask python file to app.run(debug=True, port=33507, port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)) and app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port), changing my repo to match https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku, and adding gunicorn and gevent to the requirements.txt.

App

```
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn -b :$PORT flaskapp:app
```

requirements.txt

```
gunicorn
gevent
```

Error

```
2019-07-08T19:29:05.872509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-08T19:29:05.497279+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-07-08T19:29:05.498369+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:39703 (4)
2019-07-08T19:29:05.498552+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-07-08T19:29:05.505408+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539492+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539497+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539499+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539501+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539503+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539507+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539510+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539512+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539514+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539516+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539518+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539520+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539522+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539524+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539526+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539528+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539530+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/flaskapp.py", line 4, in <module>
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539532+00:00 app[web.1]: from pml import app
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539577+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pml'
2019-07-08T19:29:05.539825+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-07-08T19:29:05.555645+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574207+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574212+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574214+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574216+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574218+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574220+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574222+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574224+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574226+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574228+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574230+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574232+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574234+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574236+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574240+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574242+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/flaskapp.py", line 4, in <module>
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574244+00:00 app[web.1]: from pml import app
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574246+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pml'
2019-07-08T19:29:05.574494+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-07-08T19:29:05.682720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-07-08T19:29:05.682883+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-07-08 19:29:05 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-07-08T19:29:05.849393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-07-08T19:35:15.978510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=randommovieroulette.herokuapp.com request_id=4e2ad446-cd8a-4136-9875-f94381259b5e fwd="173.71.157.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-08T19:35:18.311763+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=randommovieroulette.herokuapp.com request_id=154f2f1f-afeb-4765-8e05-1f908fe2d0f4 fwd="173.71.157.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The app is 'deploying', but something is wrong with the server end. Making a runtime.txt with my current python version stops the app from deploying. Should I make this a different version, then? I'm a newbie, so my deep apologies if I am making just a simple error.

Comment: You're focused on the port, but that's not the issue. Your output says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pml'". Do you intend to depend on [this](https://pypi.org/project/pml/), or is `pml` something you wrote yourself?

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was the requirements.txt it didn't have all of the packages I imported in it. For some reason, it only need some of the packages, not all of the them. THANK you so much!

Comment: I'm glad you got this working. Please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The requirements.txt did not include flask_wtf, bs4, requests, or app, all of which were imported in my flaskapp.py file. This file only included gunicorn and gevent previously.